# Create path corresponding to user input value

Tags: javascript, angular, mit-scratch

I have the code like this

```
if (LOAI === "image_clsf") {
            return {
                id: "dssama",
                name: formatMessage({
                    id: "dssama.categoryName",
                    default: "Dssama",
                    description: "Ingest some Data",
                }),
                blockIconURI: blockIconURI,
                blocks: [
                    {
                        opcode: "predictHands",
                        blockType: BlockType.REPORTER,
                        text: formatMessage({
                            id: "dssama.hands",
                            default: "Predict Hands: [paths]", 
                            description: "",
                        }),
                        arguments: {
                            paths: {
                                type: ArgumentType.STRING,
                                defaultValue: " ",
                            },
                        },
                    },
     {
                        opcode: "predictCamXuc",
                        blockType: BlockType.REPORTER,
                        text: formatMessage({
                            id: "dssama.camxuc",
                            default: "Predict Emotion: [paths]", 
                            description: "",
                        }),
                        arguments: {
                            paths: {
                                type: ArgumentType.STRING,
                                defaultValue: " ",
                            },
                        },
                    },
 ],
                menus: {
                    colorParam: {
                        acceptReporters: true,
                        items: this._initColorParam(),
                    },
                },
            };
        }
                 predictCamXuc(args) {
        let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        let id_flow_exist = searchParams.has("id_flow");
        if (!id_flow_exist) {
            return "Không tìm thấy flow ID";
        } else {
            let FLOW_ID = searchParams.get("id_flow");
            if (args.paths != " ") {
                try {
                    const reqData = {
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                inputStageId: "",
                                dataType: "image_clsf",
                                class_names: ["happy", "neutral", "sad"],
                                data: [
                                    {
                                        images: "",
                                        paths: args.paths,
                                        labels: "",
                                    },
                                ],
                            },
                        ],
                    };
  
                    const response = request(
                        "POST",
                        `http://118.70.52.237:4813/released/runflow/${FLOW_ID}`,
                        {
                            json: reqData,
                        }
                    );
                    const result = JSON.parse(response.getBody("utf8"));
                    console.log(result);
                    return result[0]["y_pred"];
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            } else {
                return "Tất cả đầu vào không được để trống";
            }
        }
    }
```

In this scratch block is a code command used to let the user enter a human emotional state but currently fixed to only have 3 emotions ( class_names: ["happy", "neutral", "sad"], ) and only 1 path can enter the value, so now when the user wants to add emotions and wants to enter more than 1 path, how will it be handled?

Detail:
How to make the block show n paths in default: "Predict Emotion: [paths]" in the opcode: "predictCamXuc" block, when the user enters the number n value in paths (default: "Predict Hands: [paths]", ) in the opcode: "predictHands"

[Example when user enter value 3 in these path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AjbP.png)
[It's show 3 paths like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MWus.png)

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you developing a [Scratch 3.0 extension](https://github.com/scratchfoundation/scratch-vm/blob/develop/docs/extensions.md)? Then please say so in your question; people cannot tell just by looking at the "mit-scratch" tag. Please explain what the blocks "Predict Hands" and "Predict Emotion" are supposed to do; the final "detail" paragraph in your question suggests the former dictates the number of parameters in the latter, but that would be very unusual to say the least. And what is a "path"? A file path? URL? A path-based gesture?